How can I speed up this ParallelMap operation?
Is there a quick way to do this?
ParallelMap[Position[gather, #] &, elements]

where gather has around 9 million elements, each element is a list containing 100 sublists of interger numbers, and elements is a list with approximately 400,000 elements.
Currently, when I execute this, it runs for more than 20 minutes without showing progress as normally expected in ParallelMap.
